# How to access the x axis index of a scipy denogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have data, for which I create a linkage model, like this:

```
model = sc.linkage(data, 'ward')
```

Where model is as follows:

```
Z = np.array([
   [  2.        ,   9.        ,  20.12172148,   2.        ],
   [  0.        ,   1.        ,  26.16772232,   2.        ],
   [ 11.        ,  12.        ,  29.40258214,   2.        ],
   [ 14.        ,  16.        ,  30.89332011,   3.        ],
   [  3.        ,   7.        ,  33.70695832,   2.        ],
   [  5.        ,  13.        ,  34.22180543,   2.        ],
   [  4.        ,  15.        ,  35.52080322,   3.        ],
   [ 17.        ,  21.        ,  45.3919152 ,   5.        ],
   [  6.        ,  20.        ,  45.56339627,   3.        ],
   [  8.        ,  23.        ,  66.42828305,   4.        ],
   [ 10.        ,  22.        ,  87.52531145,   6.        ],
   [ 18.        ,  24.        ,  93.78070161,   7.        ],
   [ 19.        ,  26.        , 124.09967826,   9.        ],
   [ 25.        ,  27.        , 160.11685636,  15.        ]])
   Z == model # returns true
```

I can then plot  this linkage model using `matplotlib`:

```
# calculate full dendrogram
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram for signature data')
plt.xlabel('sample index')
plt.ylabel('distance')
sc.dendrogram(
    model,
    leaf_rotation=90.,  # rotates the x axis labels
    leaf_font_size=8.,  # font size for the x axis labels
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, this plots the dendogram and sets the xticks to the index. I would want to replace this with actual labels, which are

```
labels = ['wood', 'stone', 'flora', 'liquid', 'food', 'metal', 'ceramic', 
          'sky', 'glass', 'paper', 'animal', 'skin', 'fabrics', 'gem', 'ground']
```

as in, the first tick on the x-axis reads 10. Which would be labels[10]. However, I can't find out how to access this index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to access the index. [`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) provides a `labels` argument which you should use to supply your labels.

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, labels=labels, ....)
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Z = np.array([
   [  2.        ,   9.        ,  20.12172148,   2.        ],
   [  0.        ,   1.        ,  26.16772232,   2.        ],
   [ 11.        ,  12.        ,  29.40258214,   2.        ],
   [ 14.        ,  16.        ,  30.89332011,   3.        ],
   [  3.        ,   7.        ,  33.70695832,   2.        ],
   [  5.        ,  13.        ,  34.22180543,   2.        ],
   [  4.        ,  15.        ,  35.52080322,   3.        ],
   [ 17.        ,  21.        ,  45.3919152 ,   5.        ],
   [  6.        ,  20.        ,  45.56339627,   3.        ],
   [  8.        ,  23.        ,  66.42828305,   4.        ],
   [ 10.        ,  22.        ,  87.52531145,   6.        ],
   [ 18.        ,  24.        ,  93.78070161,   7.        ],
   [ 19.        ,  26.        , 124.09967826,   9.        ],
   [ 25.        ,  27.        , 160.11685636,  15.        ]])

labels = ['wood', 'stone', 'flora', 'liquid', 'food', 'metal', 'ceramic', 
          'sky', 'glass', 'paper', 'animal', 'skin', 'fabrics', 'gem', 'ground']

# calculate full dendrogram
plt.figure()
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram for signature data')
plt.xlabel('sample index')
plt.ylabel('distance')
sc.dendrogram(
    Z,
    labels=labels,
    leaf_rotation=90.,  # rotates the x axis labels
    leaf_font_size=8.,  # font size for the x axis labels
)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You nailed it :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have dendogram module but the following should work for you. The idea is:

- Create an axis instance `ax` and pass it to `dendogram` plot as axis argument
- Get the existing x-ticklabels, and convert them to integers. Use these integers as indices to access the values from `labels`. This is just to have the labels in the order as you want them to be displayed on the x-axis
- Set these new labels using `set_xticklabels`

---

Following is the relevant piece of code you can use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))

sc.dendrogram(
    model,
    leaf_rotation=90.,  
    leaf_font_size=8.,  ax=ax)

fig.canvas.draw()

new_labels = [labels[int(i.get_text())] for i in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed to know.